# How to filter out by attribute in objects FK object

Tags: django, orm

I am trying to filter out objects using attributes of objects referenced via Foreign Key

```
>>> sa = Survey.objects.all()
>>> sa.filter(student.gender='M')
File "<console>", line 1
  SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Is there a different way to do this? List surveys for Male students?

My models look like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
   # ...
   GENDER = (
     ('M','Male'),
     ('F', 'Female'),
   )
   gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)

class Survey(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) explains exactly how to do this.

```
sa.filter(student__gender='M')
```

Comment: Ahh, my bad. I was reading documentation for `filter()` on this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#filter and did not see that. Thanks.